# How to fake a touch to standard iOS keyboard

Tags: ios, keyboard-events

Here's my setup: I want to programmatically...

- Raise the built-in keyboard (by giving focus to a text field)
- Programmatically animate a finger graphic moving over the keyboard.
- Fake a **tap** on the keyboard and have the keyboard respond to that tap.

The use-case is to create a video showing "look, you can type, and this is what happens...", but with a stylized and partially transparent finger-image, rather than somebody's actual finger blocking the view.

Related: I can map the X/Y coordinates for my video easily enough, but bonus points if anyone can help me get the position of a given key on the keyboard, thus simplifying my writing of the routine `fakeTypeText: @"Hello World!"` to move the point of the finger to the correct location.

Thanks!

**EDIT:** Use case sample code...

```
- (void) fakeTypeText: (NSString*) text
{
    int len = (int) text.length;
    for (int ii = 0 ; ii < len ; ++ii)
    {
        char oneChar = [text characterAtIndex: ii];
        // *** BONUS POINTS ***
        CGPoint kbPoint = CGPointZero; // ?!?!  Point on keyboard of the oneChar-key.
        [UIView animateWithDuration: duration
                         animations: ^{
                             self.fingerView.center = kbPoint;
                         }
                         completion: ^(BOOL finished) {
                             // *** MAIN QUESTION ***
                             [self fakeTapEventOnKeyboard: oneChar]; // ?!?!  How to do this?
                         }
         ];
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**  To clarify further, the behaviour I want is, when I call `fakeTapEventOnKeyboard`, I want iOS to behave as if the user had tapped that key.  Specifically, the key should highlight (including the little popup-key graphic), make the key-tapped sound and type the key into the firstResponder field, if any.

Comment: Is it overkill to create a bunch of NSOperation that has dependencies on each other (the dependency should dictate the order) and then start all of them?

Comment: and of course since the operations contain animation you probably want to add them to the mainQueue.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking, Enzo.  I know how to do the threading and background processing; the question is about ***what*** do I need to do *in* the NSOperation?  That is: how do I fake the event to the built-in keyboard?

Comment: Assuming you need to pass App Store review (no private APIs), I think you'll need to create a fake lookalike keyboard, maybe using the new screenshot API introduced in iOS 7. Even then, you won't know where the buttons are, especially once iOS 8 comes out and there are all kinds of third-party keyboards.